# Unable to parse ^ character

Tags: java

Okay, Now I am able to parse space which was my previous problem. Now my parser is almost ready but has a defect which I am unable to figure out.

I am able to retrieve Data after segments(see code) and data in between pipes.
What I am not able to get to is a level up and retrieve data which is contained between pipes and seperated by ^.

Eg.

```
Input String is A|1|2|3^4|
Expected Output
element1        A
element2        1
element3        2
element4.1      3
element4.2      4
```

However, My current output is coming to be

```
element1        A
element2        1
element3        2
element4       3^4
```

I am recieving exception
1 [Ljava.lang.String;@1786e64 with various ids after @

The commented code given below is creating problem.

CODE:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
str=scanner.nextLine();
System.out.println(str);
segments="(A)|(B)|(C)|(D)";
pipe="[\\s+\\|+\\+]";
carat="[\\^+]";
for(i=0;i<token_type1.length;i++)
{
token_type2=token_type1[i].toString().split(pipe);
for(j=0;j<token_type2.length;j++)
{           
/*
token_type3=token_type2.toString().split(carat);    
for(k=0;k<token_type3.length;k++)
System.out.println("\t"+(k+1)+" "+token_type3[k]);
*/
System.out.println((j+1)+"\t"+token_type2[j]);
}
System.out.println();
}
```

Please advise.

Comment: Add `System.out.println(str);` right after `str=scanner.next();` and you'll see why. Also, you don't need that while loop, because it's executing the same command every time, once is enough.

Comment: Hmmmm...thats a revelation. it did not take 4 as an input at all. Shall I change from scanner to Bufferedreader?

Comment: Is this thread still open. I need some advice.

Comment: If it's a new question, compose a new question. Otherwise just edit your question.

Comment: @jlordo -any idea about this updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will transform your input to your desired output (save the classes in two different files)

> Parser.java

```
public class Parser {

    public static final String ELEMENT_DELIM_REGEX = "\\|";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "A|1|2|3^4|";
        String[] tokens = input.split(ELEMENT_DELIM_REGEX);
        Element[] elements = new Element[tokens.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
            elements[i] = new Element(i + 1, tokens[i]);
        }
        for (Element element : elements) {
            System.out.println(element);
        }
    }

}
```

and

> Element.java

```
public class Element {

    public static final String SUB_ELEMENT_DELIM_REGEX = "\\^";

    private int number;

    private String[] content;

    public Element(int number, String content) {
        this.number = number;
        this.content = content.split(SUB_ELEMENT_DELIM_REGEX);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (content.length == 1) {
            return "Element " + number + "\t" + content[0];
        }
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
            str.append("Element " + number + "." + (i+1) + "\t" + content[i] + "\n");   
        }
        // Delete the last \n
        str.replace(str.length() - 1, str.length(), "");
        return str.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: sry for completely rewriting it, I couldn't reuse much of your code.

Comment: Thanks for that @jlordo. Let me try that and will get back.

Comment: Your code works. :) I am going to model it and develop my own. One quick question...the element class that you have defined...is that an enum? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Than you might want to upvote and accept ;) If it were an enum, it would have been declared as `public enum Element {`. A look at the code shows it is declared as a class: `public class Element {`

Comment: Vote up requires 15 reps... I have 6 :(I did the tick though.

Comment: Hey @jlordo I did my research,The element class is an iterator class.

Comment: Than give it another name, that was the first thing pop into my mind. Also, you're allowed to have same class names in different packages.

Comment: Sorry I was not able to complete my question before enter..:( I need to add a variable tag, that can define those elements. For e.g. element1-element12 shall display A1 -A12 if element1.value=="A" and element12-element24 B12-B24 and like wise. I tried inserting this tag variable in the element call itself from parser.java but tag is taking value of null everytime.Still in process of looking ...

Comment: I also defined tag and changed its value everytime...by performing a check on the value of element. But its not taking ...modified the element class constructor to this.tag= tag and call to elements[i]=new element(tag,i+1,token_type[i])

Comment: OK, number 1: never compare strings with `==`, use `.equals()`. number 2: I don't understand what you mean, but since you have a new problem,  I suggest you compose a new question where you show what you have right now, what you are trying to do and what the problem is (Input, expected output, actual output)

Comment: OK will open a new question soon after fighting with this problem. I am doing this project for self learning basis, so i really dont know what all problems going to come. :)

Comment: just hang in there, it's learning by doing ;) Should I see your new question, I'll try to answer it...

Comment: Modifying this question itself.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend modifying the question, because there are already answers with upvotes and accepts here, not many people will look at it. Your facing new problems, so feel free to ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Use method `Sting.split()`. Think about all your delimiters and put they all as an argument to split. Be aware that split works with regex, so special characters like `|` must be escaped. For example line:

`String[] tokens = str.split("[\\s+\\|]");`

should create expected tokens from your input.

Comment: no, because he reads input once with `scanner.next()`, which will only return the input up to the first whitespace.

Comment: Okay...What i did was to replace scanner.next() with scanner.nextLine() so it is able to sense that there exists 4. This is one problem solved. working on the other..

Comment: So, do not use `Scanner`. Use `BufferedReader.readLine()` instead.

Comment: I think i got the solution I was looking for. It was problem with the input method and not with my Regex or delim_set. I used scanner.nextLine() for input which advances to the next character after whitespaces as well for input. And modified the delim set to delim="[\\s+\\|^]+"; That worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Scanner() by default has space as delimeter. So if you do scanner.next() again then you will get the remaining input part, '4'.

You can set your own delimeter by using `usedelimeter(String pattern)` api of Scanner class.