# Unable to display Tag

Tags: java

Okay I am following on another question i posted a week ago. 
[Unable to parse ^ character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855988/unable-to-parse-character)

My current situation is that now I am able to parse the required Regex and create subsequent elements. I have created tags for each element type .

For eg my input string is A|1|2|3^4|B||1|2|3^4^5

So my tags in this string are A and B

My Output shall be (expected)

```
A1      1 
A2      2
A3.1    3 
A3.2    4
B1      (BLANK) //not B
B2      1
B3      2
B4.1    3
B4.2    4
B4.3    5
```

The reason B1 should be blank because input is B||1|2.
My current output is coming to be

```
element1    A
element2    1
element3.1  2
element3.2  3
element4    4
element5    B
element6     
element7.1  2
element7.2  3
element7.3  4
element7.4  5
```

Basically, I am trying to construct an HL7 parser. replacements with the accurate tags are done to avoid confusion and maintain confidentiality. The code is as below.

> public class Parser {
>
> ```
> public static final String ELEMENT_DELIM_REGEX = "\\|";
>
> public static void main(String[] args) {
>     String input = "A|1|2|3^4|";
>     String[] tokens = input.split(ELEMENT_DELIM_REGEX);
>     Element[] elements = new Element[tokens.length];
>     for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
>         elements[i] = new Element(i + 1, tokens[i]);
>     }
>     for (Element element : elements) {
>         System.out.println(element);
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> }

and

```
Element.java
```

> public class Element {
>
> ```
> public static final String SUB_ELEMENT_DELIM_REGEX = "\\^";
>
> private int number;
>
> private String[] content;
>
> public Element(int number, String content) {
>     this.number = number;
>     this.content = content.split(SUB_ELEMENT_DELIM_REGEX);
> }
>
> @Override
> public String toString() {
>     if (content.length == 1) {
>         return "Element " + number + "\t" + content[0];
>     }
>     StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
>     for (int i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
>         str.append("Element " + number + "." + (i+1) + "\t" + content[i] + "\n");   
>     }
>     // Delete the last \n
>     str.replace(str.length() - 1, str.length(), "");
>     return str.toString();
> } }
> ```

Comment: Question should be self-contained. Please don't require us to read another question (which is not a thread, by the way, as this is not a forum).

Comment: added the code...I was asked to create another question since I and @jlordo had been discussing about this for quite sometime.

Comment: Creating a separate question and linking to it is fine. Just don't *require* us to read both.

Comment: @SiddharthSharma You didn't change any of the code I provided in the previous question. Also for your example input I get different output. There is element `3`, `4.1` and `4.2`, **not** `3.1`, `3.2` and `4`. Did you try anything to integrate the tag handling, yet?

Comment: @jlordo I did that but I was not able to find a proper place to insert tag.The output used to vary a lot with inserting of tag. my efforts resembles what you did in the element class , i did the same thing. But I did not tried using the collections framework as in List. Going through your code only.

Comment: @SiddharthSharma as you see in my answer, I had to use a dynamic List, because you don't know how many Elements there will be at the beginning. A fixed size array wouldn't be an elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be achieved by a few little changes in the two classes: (Ask me if you don't understand what's happening in the code, I wrote only a few comments and but tried to keep it self-explaining)

```
public class Parser {

    public static final String ELEMENT_DELIM_REGEX = "\\|";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "A|1|2|3^4|B||1|2|3^4^5";
        String[] tokens = input.split(ELEMENT_DELIM_REGEX);
        List<Element> elements = new ArrayList<Element>();
        String currentTag = "";
        int elementCounter = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
            if (tokens[i].matches("\\p{Alpha}+")) {
                currentTag = tokens[i];
                elementCounter = 1;
                continue;
            }
            elements.add(new Element(elementCounter++, currentTag,  tokens[i]));
        }
        for (Element element : elements) {
            System.out.println(element);
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Element {

    public static final String SUB_ELEMENT_DELIM_REGEX = "\\^";

    private int number;

    private String[] content;

    private String tag;

    public Element(int number, String tag, String content) {
        this.number = number;
        this.content = content.split(SUB_ELEMENT_DELIM_REGEX);
        this.tag = tag;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (content.length == 1) {
            return tag + "" + number + "\t" + content[0];
        }
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
            str.append(tag + "" + number + "." + (i+1) + "\t" + content[i] + "\n");   
        }
        // Delete the last \n
        str.replace(str.length() - 1, str.length(), "");
        return str.toString();
    } 
}
```

Output (for your input `A|1|2|3^4|B||1|2|3^4^5` )

```
A1      1
A2      2
A3.1    3
A3.2    4
B1  
B2      1
B3      2
B4.1    3
B4.2    4
B4.3    5
```

Comment: @SiddharthSharma something not working with this solution? Any reason for not accepting?

Comment: @jlordo...Its working as expected.I need to polish it a bit...I was sleeping so could not accept it.

Comment: I am converting the input from Single line A|1|2|3^4|B||1|2|3^4^5 to multiline input. After several trials I realized that it cannot be done via the console. So I am moving the input style to a file based input. Lets see how it goes :)

Comment: I am sure it can be done via console. But a file based input makes more sense anyway.